# Spring boot delete object from database based on a OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i've got an "appointment" entity object(table) AND dates_doctor_available entity build like this

```
@Entity
public class Appointment {
.....
 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "date_time_available_fk", nullable=true)
 private DatesDoctorAvailable datesDoctorAvailable;
 ......
```

AND

```
@Entity
  public class DatesDoctorAvailable {
   ....
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="datesDoctorAvailable")
  private Appointment appointment;
  ....
```

now i wish from a controller to remove the Database entry based on the "date_time_available_fk" Using "Appointment" object. For example something like

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/show/scheduled/{id}" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String gettAppointmentDel(Model model, @PathVariable String id, Principal 
       principal, 
       @ModelAttribute("appointment") Appointment appointment, 
       @ModelAttribute("datess.dateID") 
      DatesDoctorAvailable datesDoctoravailable) {
       ......
      //this part below i want to make it work
      appointmentService.deleteByDatesDoctorAvailable(
       appointment.getDatesDoctorAvailable(
        datesDoctorAvailableService.findByDateID(Long.parseLong(id))));
        .....
     }
```

where inside service there is a data object access something like this(they are interfaces)

```
@Override
public Appointment deleteByDatesDoctorAvailable(DatesDoctorAvailable 
datesDoctorAvailable) {
    return  
    appointmentDao.deleteByDatesDoctorAvailable(datesDoctorAvailable);

}
```

where id is the date_time_available_fk number i want to pass(i already have it from thymeleaf) to the Appointment object

i want to avoid using @Query if this can happen.

**UPDATE**
i actually figured it out i will give the solution in the morning for future troublers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution**
i could not fetch the object information from database with above as i said in order to delete it afterwards so i did this(created new object Appointment)

```
   Appointment appointmentFind = 
   appointmentService.findByDatesDoctorAvailable(
   datesDoctorAvailableService.findByDateID(Long.parseLong(id)));
```

that way i could retrieve the information then delete it like this.

```
   appointmentService.deleteScheduleById(appointmentFind.getId());
```

after getting id from url request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/show/scheduled/{id}" ,method = 
RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAppointmentDel(Model model, @PathVariable String id, 
Principal principal, @ModelAttribute("appointment") Appointment 
appointment, @ModelAttribute("datess.dateID") DatesDoctorAvailable 
datesDoctoravailable) {
```

---------------inside view thymeleaf------------

```
  <td><button type="button"  
  th:onclick=
 "|window.location.href='/appointment/show/scheduled/${datess.dateID}'|" 
  th-text="(id1=${datess.dateID})" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
  Cancel it
 </button></td>
```

-------------------inside Services---------------

---Service:---

```
 @Override
  public Appointment findByDatesDoctorAvailable(DatesDoctorAvailable 
   datesDoctorAvailable) {
    return 
       appointmentDao.findByDatesDoctorAvailable(datesDoctorAvailable);
}
```

---DAO:-----

```
     Appointment findByDatesDoctorAvailable(DatesDoctorAvailable 
     datesDoctorAvailable);
```

---Service:---

```
    void deleteScheduleById(@Param("id") Long id);
    @Override
    public void deleteScheduleById(Long id) {
    appointmentDao.deleteScheduleById(id);  
   }
```

---DAO:-----

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("delete from Appointment where id = :id")
void deleteScheduleById(@Param("id") Long id);
```